# How do I get Selenium in Python to select a dropdown that doesn't appear to have <select> and <option> tags?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The code for the website's dropdown is:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_divAddressVerficationLbl" class="rowLeftPad50 label" data-argosy-tooltip="25">
        Address Verification
</div>
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_divAddressVerficationCombo" class="rowLeft ">
     <div id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default" style="width:153px;white-space:normal;">
    <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
        <tr class="rcbReadOnly">
            <td style="width:100%;" class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$basicSettingsCntrl$rdComboAddressVerification" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification_Input" value="Yes" readonly="readonly" tabindex="7" /></td>
            <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display:none;"><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;"><ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;"><li class="rcbItem ">Yes</li><li class="rcbItem ">No</li></ul></div></div></div><input id="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification_ClientState" type="hidden" />
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the guides I've seen on Selenium, most of them are accessing a dropdown that has a `Select` tag, with options have an `option` tag. I'm guessing this dropdown is created or maintained in javascript? Is there a way to manipulate this using Selenium? Or can I use something else within Python to change the dropdown?

Here's my relevant code, most recently when I tried a workaround to simply use sending an ARROW_UP key to select something else, which throws an error:

```
#find and click dropdown
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification").click()
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_basicSettingsCntrl_rdComboAddressVerification") 
#will move selector up to yes. If already at top, will remain at top
element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)    
#click submit
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnSaveCustomerDetails").click()
```

The usual Select does not work for obvious reasons, at least from what I've tried from a few various guides on youtube and the Selenium documentation. I am not seeing a way to interact with it in general.

I thought I might have a workaround- to simply send an ARROW_UP to select the above item in the list but it throws an error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Is it a public URL so we can access?

Comment: It is not. What else can I do to assist?
EDIT: Here's a dropdown that seems to work on the same principle on the site that IS public: https://www.kingstonprintcenter.com/0n3HG6n/Store#Category:51146:Finance

If you click the item (or click add to cart) the modal that pops up has a dropdown that appears to work the same way. Not exactly the same but might be able to get it to work if it is possible to get that dropdown to work.

Comment: There are _ReadOnly_, `readonly="readonly"`, `style="z-index:6000;"` and `style="display:none;"` I'm not sure from where should I start asking.

Comment: Just saw you posted. See my above edit.

Comment: If you can rebase your question wrt the demo site, I can attempt to answer. Else I'm not sure whats happening in your specific usecase.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium this was a rather easy problem to solve. In fact, I knew the answer to this problem before looking at the alternate URL that Kyle provided. But, even if I didn't know the answer, anyone could've quickly solve the problem if they would've examined it. This is how I was able to provide the two Xpath expressions in  my answer. I am not sure why you would say (coming from an expert) you weren't sure what was happening in this case. Haven't you faced this problem with dropdowns before? That is shocking to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you will need to create an XPath locator to locate the
`<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span>` element inside the "fancybox". Perhaps something like this:

```
//div[@class='fancybox-outer']//span[@class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down']
```

Once you obtain this element, send a click to it to expand.

Next, locate the list items. Use an explicit wait to set timeout and wait for elements to be visible. Lastly, locate the desired listed element and click on it. For the example in the comments, you could locate the desired listed item by its `data-offset-index` attribute. For example, to select the second listed item, you will need an expression like this

```
//div[@class='fancybox-outer']/following::ul/li[@data-offset-index="2"]
```

The reason for this is because the list is not nested inside the "fancybox." It is actually after this element. The *following* XPath axes uses a relative position (in this case the "fancybox" element) an searches for the given element that exist only after the base element. In essence, you are looking for a `ul` element that exist **after** the "fancybox" that contains an `li` element with the given *data_offset_index*.